# Short exact sequence on modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

Let L, M, N, be A-modules, with A commutative, unit ring.  I'm trying to prove that if $f: L \rightarrow M$ is injective and $g: M \rightarrow N$ is surjective then the short  sequence is exact

$0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N  \rightarrow 0$

I have problem when trying to prove $\operatorname{Im}(f) = \operatorname{Ker}(g)$.

Some texts say that it is a consequence of the facts
$0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M$ is exact $\iff$ $f$ is injective.

$M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0 $ is exact $\iff$ $g$ is surjective.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample**:

$\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot 4}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}$ is injective, and $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$ is surjective, but $$0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}\overset{\cdot 4}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow 0$$ is not exact since $(4)\neq (2)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you, You have reason, we need a third condition